# x-editable select with options value from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, x-editable

So I'm using x-editable for bootstrap, which is awsome for me.

can anyone help me how to set option values from mysql database into x-editable select options

this is my php code

```
$result1 = ("SELECT * FROM users where type='agent'") or mysql_error(); 
    $users=mysql_query($result1);
        while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($users)){

        ?>
        <option name="agent" value = "<?php echo $rowa['username']; ?>" >
            <?php echo $rowa['username']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm actually wrong. I'll provide a better example.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're going to want to do is actually create a JSON string which you will put into an `anchor` element. Let's see what that looks like.

First, you need to push the usernames into an array object it, then json encode it. That'll look like this:

```
$usernames = array();
while(.....){
    $usernames[] = $rowa['username'];
}
$usernames = json_encode($usernames);

<a href="#" 
    id="username" //your reference 
    data-type="select" //so the x-editable library makes a select list
    data-name="username" 
    data-pk="1" 
    data-value="5" 
    data-original-title="Select Username" 
    data-source="<?php echo $usernames?"> //this is your JSON array of usernames.
 ">
    Username
</a>
```

And this will produce a select list of usernames.

[Here's your functioning jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jobjs7pf/)

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon the same problems as Johannes Kiehl.
However, after a little investigation I found the following and finally fixed it - somehow. It may not be the most elegant approach, hence ideas for improvement are very welcome.

Here's what I wanted to achieve:
In a select field, results from a MySQL-Query shall be displayed. Upon success on the select, I want to refresh a div with the new content, also loaded via an external PHP-file.

Problem in the solution mentioned above:
The JSON-Array given back by PHP (in my case) looks like this:

```
[{"value":"1","text":"TEXT1"},{"value":"2","text":"TEXT2"}]
```

The array used in the fiddle looks like:

```
{'1': 'something', '2': 'another thing'}
```

So I assumed that the double quotes may be the problem.
I did then in PHP:

```
$myarray = str_replace("\"", "'", $myarray);
```

And easy as one-two-three it worked. Here's the whole thing complete:

**Javascript to define the editable select element:**

```
$('#myselect-id').editable( {
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        $( "#mydiv-id" ).load("loading-external-results.php");
        }
    });
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
$myarray = array();
$query = "SELECT id, field1 FROM mytable";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $myarray[] = array('value' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['field1']);

}
$myarray = json_encode($myarray);
$myarray = str_replace("\"", "'", $myarray);
?>
```

**HTML to generate the select-element:**

```
    <a href="#" id="myselect-id"
            data-type="select"
            data-name="fieldname-in-table-to-update"
            data-pk="id-of-the-affected-mysql-row"
            data-value="5"
            data-url="post.php"
            data-source="'.$myarray.'">Text for Select</a>
        <div id="mydiv-id">
Some Content, replaced on success of select element.
    </div>
```